# BGP protocol, vantage points

Tags: routes, packets, bgp

Is there any place where can I obtain the routing table details of all the BGP vantage points located across the world? Like is there a method to collect and read the BGP dump? Or how can I get it from the RIPE Atlas? Or any other methods? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get BGP dump for any AS number (knowing its IP) on http://www.netconfigs.com/php/bgp.php

The full database of AS numbers and IPs is available on bgp.he.net and also in RIR's WHOIS

Alternatively you can use Robtex to get data on BGP networks of each ASN, example https://www.robtex.com/as/as42154.html